# easiest way to make data frames in python without pandas package?

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm deploying a web app that can't use pandas. I'm using python3 and elastic beanstalk on aws, and various dependencies just aren't available at the moment.

I only need pandas in a single function - the usage is pretty simple: make some data frames, and search them via `df.loc`. --> Does anyone know a good alternative to pandas that has a `df.loc[index, col]` functionality?

Comment: If you don't have pandas, get pandas. Using the built in dict object to capture a 750 Mb file can take up over 20 gb ram while pandas will read it with like 4.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsJLLEwUYZM

Comment: can you use numpy? Otherwise, the next best thing might be a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `numpy`.  Also, indexing `numpy` is faster than indexing w/ `pandas`

```
Ar_data = np.array([["gyrados","raichu","mu","dragonair","vaporeon"],["water","electric","normal","dragon","water"], [0,0,0,1,2]]).T
Ar_data
# array([['gyrados', 'water', '0'],
#        ['raichu', 'electric', '0'],
#        ['mu', 'normal', '0'],
#        ['dragonair', 'dragon', '1'],
#        ['vaporeon', 'water', '2']], 
#       dtype='<U9')

# Index w/ ints `.iloc`
Ar_data[3,1]
# 'dragon'

fields = ["pokemon","status","meta"]
observations = ["p1","p2","p3","p4","p5"]

# Index w/ labels `.loc`
Ar_data[3,fields.index("pokemon")]
# 'dragonair'

Ar_data[observations.index("p4"),fields.index("pokemon")]
# 'dragonair'

# Time it
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(Ar_data, columns=fields, index=observations)
%timeit DF_data.iloc[3,1]
%timeit Ar_data[3,1]
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop
# The slowest run took 21.69 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 384 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 10):

You best option would be to use lists in a dict:

```
df_eq = {'col1' : [list, of, column, data],
         'col2' : [list, of, column, data],
         ...,
         'coln-1' : [list, of, column, data],
         'coln' : [list, of, column, data]}
```

Then you can use something like `loc`:

```
df_eq['coln'][idx]
```